# Regular expression in Powershell

Tags: regex, powershell

I am looking for regular expression in Powershell to check if string contains some text which starts with `$` and end with `$` present.

Ex. If I search in `"/SUBSCRIPTIONS/$paramSubscriptionId$/RESOURCEGROUPS"` string then it should return `paramSubscriptionId` as a result.

I am using `'[$?$]'` but it's not working as expected. Can someone please help me on this?

Comment: Could you please share the code you are using? Without it, *it's not working as expected* is too unclear.

Comment: Have you tried a regex explainer yet? See e.g. [this one](https://regex101.com/r/dC5gO1/1), it's pretty clear about your regex and should be a clear hint to what's still missing.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Uhm, I'd guess something like `$s -match '[$?$]'`.

Comment: did you try `'\$(.+)\$'` ?

Comment: I am using this code: "/SUBSCRIPTIONS/$paramSubscriptionId$/RESOURCEGROUPS" -match '[$?$]'

Comment: Where's the code (even if it didn't work)? This can be done with both `-replace` and `-match` ++, so we need to know what you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$str = '/SUBSCRIPTIONS/$paramSubscriptionId$/RESOURCEGROUPS'
if($str -match '\$(.+?)\$') { $Matches[1] }
```

Comment: Thanks @Frode . If I try with `$str = "/SUBSCRIPTIONS/$paramSubscriptionId$/RESOURCEGROUPS"` then I don't get any output

Comment: You need single quotes to make it a literal string. `$` is special in powershell (variable-prefix).

Comment: Right. but this lines comes from Different file (.json) which contains " " instead of ' '

Comment: if you read a file, it will behave like `'string'`. It's only with manually typed strings (like when you're testing now) that you need to worry about single vs double quotes.  If the file itself includes quotes, then that would be the same as `'"string"'`

Comment: Thanks. I will try and get back to you.